# ‘Flex Error #1001: Digest mismatch with RSL’ when updating *just* the Flex web application

Tags: apache-flex, ant, rsl

I get the following error when I update just the Flex web application’s swf file:

**Flex Error #1001: Digest mismatch with RSL**

I understand why this is happening (because the digest that was in catalog.xml of the RSLs don’t match what the Flex web application’s swf file is expecting) but can’t find a way to successfully update just the Flex web application.  My question is how can this be done using ANT with Flex 3.6 SDK?

I have attempted to have the Flex web application ignore the digest value by setting the ‘compute-digest’ property to false on the compc tag for all RSLs:

```
<compc compiler.as3="true" 
  output="${temp-swc-dir}/@{name}.swc" 
  incremental="false" 
  fork="false" 
  compiler.show-deprecation-warnings="false" 
  compiler.verbose-stacktraces="${VERBOSE}" 
  compute-digest="false"
  >
```

But when the mxmlc is executed, it fails mentioning about the digest.  Is there something that needs to change in my mxmlc tag?

```
<mxmlc file="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/revolution/src/${SWF_NAME}.mxml" 
    output="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/${SWF_NAME}.swf" 
    actionscript-file-encoding="UTF-8" 
    keep-generated-actionscript="false" 
    incremental="false" 
    debug="@{qa-build}" 
    fork="false" 
    static-link-runtime-shared-libraries="false" 
    use-network="true"
    >

    <runtime-shared-library-path path-element="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/swc/as3corelib.swc">
        <url rsl-url="rsl/as3corelib.swf" />
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

    <runtime-shared-library-path path-element="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/swc/asx.swc">
        <url rsl-url="rsl/asx.swf" />
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

    <runtime-shared-library-path path-element="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/swc/top-level-tools.swc">
        <url rsl-url="rsl/top-level-tools.swf" />
    </runtime-shared-library-path>

    <source-path path-element="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/revolution/src" />

    <!-- list of path elements that form the roots of ActionScript class hierarchies. -->
    <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" />

    <!-- list of SWC files or directories that contain SWC files. -->
    <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs" append="true">
        <include name="framework.swc" />
    </compiler.library-path>

    <compiler.library-path dir="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/swc" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc" />
    </compiler.library-path>

    <compiler.library-path dir="${target-dir}/@{build-directory}/revolution/libs" append="true">
        <include name="*.swc" />
    </compiler.library-path>

</mxmlc>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Flex comes with a tool to update digests. It's called "digest". I documented the steps needed to create RSLs from third party SWC libraries in my Wiki ... To me it looks as if your RSL and SWC no longer match. https://dev.c-ware.de/confluence/display/PUBLIC/Creating+RSLs+from+your+3rd+party+libs
So if you would just create the RSL from the SWC you are using you should be on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for linking that article, as of yesterday I didn't know the optimizer and digest executable existed.  But I have the source for the RSLs for the Flex web application.  And when my build script runs, it creates a SWC which then the MXMLC uses to create (via runtime-shared-library-path tag) the RSL SWF file.  My issue is updating the Flex web application on the server without updating the RSL SWF files.  How can this be done?